# Access variable from code run in "eval" in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I know using eval is not at all recommended and I have read this link too. [Set Variable inside Eval (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889885/set-variable-inside-eval-javascript)

However, this is what I want to do. Lets say we have some code in a textbox. So I have to take that text, and then find out all the global variables, functions and objects in that code. 
My idea was to wrap the code in a namespace, eval it and then iterate through the properties of the namespace to get the results. However, even though the eval runs successfully, I can't access the variable defined there. Is there a better solution or some other way to get this working.

http://jsfiddle.net/DbrEF/2/ - This is the Fiddle here.

The "var code" could actually be arbitrary code. I know its unsafe to do it but I need it for a different context. 
Thanks

Comment: close voter - how is this too localized?

Answer (score 5):

In 2015, [creating a `Function` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) is your best bet here, rather than using `eval`:

```
new Function('arg1', 'arg2', 'return arg1 + arg2')(3,4) // returns 7
```

Answer (score 0):

[here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DbrEF/4/) on safely using eval using ["use strict"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode)

```
window.onload = function(){
    'use strict'; 
    //use strict forces to run code in "strict mode" 
    //use strict prevents eval from 
    //contaminating the immediate scope

    //let's test with "foo"
    var foo = 'lol';

    //now code has "foo" but using "use strict" 
    //makes code in eval stay in eval
    //note that at the last of the code, foo is "returned"
    var code = 'var foo = {name: "Spock",greeting: function() {return "Hello " + foo.name;}}; foo';

    //store eval'ed code in evalO
    var evalstore = eval(code);

    console.log(evalstore); //code in eval stays in here, which is "inner foo"
    console.log(foo);       //"outer foo" is unharmed and daisy fresh
}​;
```

---

so whatever code you have, contain it in a function which will serve as your namespace. then have that function returned to the outside world stored as a variable. [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DbrEF/6/) shows how it can be constructed, however, works only if code is in object literal notation.

```
window.onload = function() {
    'use strict';

    var ns = 'lol';

    //code must be an object literal
    var code = '{name: "Spock",greeting: function(){return "Hello " + foo.name;}}';

    //store in a constructor to be returned
    var constructorString = 'var ns = function(){return ' + code + '}; ns'; 

    var evalNs = eval(constructorString);     //type function/constructor
    var evalObj = new evalNs()                //object instance

    console.log(evalNs);  //constructor
    console.log(evalObj); //the namespaced object
    console.log(ns);      //outer "ns" preserved
};​
```

​

Comment: That does seem to work. However, what happens when the code is something like this                                                                            function Dog() {
    this.greet = function() {
      return 'Hello world';
    }

    this.dontgreet = function() {
      return 'hello world';
    }
  }                                                                         Also how would it handle multiline code ? I am unable to use your example with what I pasted above. Any ideas ? Somehow this comment screwed up the code formatting above but its multiline.

Comment: updated my code. it's proof of concept, but having arbitrary code is really risky

Comment: I agree. arbitrary code is risky. However, the purpose is kind of a small ide kind of thing where we can do introspection on the objects. I see how you are implementing this but instead of your example if we take the function Dog() example I get the following error - 'missing : after property id' when running the eval. - http://pastebin.com/s6r5wjdc (This is the constructorString from my example). http://jsfiddle.net/DbrEF/7/

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck using a Javascript parser, like the one used by JSHint/JSLint

Comment: aah that's something I was trying to avoid on this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what exactly OP was looking for but another option is to use outside variables to store values generated inside eval, as in:

```
var value;
var code = 'var foo = 42';
code = code.replace('var foo', 'value');
eval(code);
value // returns 42;
```